# CSS error jQuery Mobile Themeroller

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I used jQuery Molbile's Themeroller to create a theme for my jQuery Mobile web app.
The CSS contains errors according to Aptana studio 3.

```
.ui-overlay {
background: #666;
opacity: .5;
filter: Alpha(Opacity=50);
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

There's a syntax error: Unexpected token "=" on this line:

```
filter: Alpha(Opacity=50);
```

How can I resolve this ?

Comment: You dont need it as you have defined `opacity: 0.5;` remove it! Its also a deprecated attrib in IE9. it usually works for IE 5-7versions see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// for IE5-7
filter: alpha(opacity=50);


// for IE8
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";

// for all other browsers including IE9
opacity: .5;
```

Based on your requirement choose if you want that attrib to be placed or not. Hope it helps

**EDIT:** useful MSDN's [**link**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/08/17/ie9-opacity-and-alpha.aspx) showing the best practices of CSS in IE9 & other versions

Answer (score 1):

That line is for IE compatibility on opacity stuff. Do you need it? If you don't, remove the line. If you need it… there's nothing you can do.